# Nodejs: Child process not exiting after calling unref()

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, fork

According to the nodejs docs, the [`detached`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#optionsdetached) option on creating a `ChildProcess` allows the child process to continue running after the parent exits.

And the [`unref()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#subprocessunref) method on `ChildProcess` allows the parent to exit and not wait for the child process to exit.

> By default, the parent will wait for the detached child to exit. To prevent the parent from waiting for a given subprocess to exit, use the subprocess.unref() method. Doing so will cause the parent's event loop to not include the child in its reference count, allowing the parent to exit independently of the child, unless there is an established IPC channel between the child and the parent.

> When using the detached option to start a long-running process, the process will not stay running in the background after the parent exits unless it is provided with a stdio configuration that is not connected to the parent. If the parent's stdio is inherited, the child will remain attached to the controlling terminal.

I am trying to create a child process that would do some long-duration work, and I don't want the parent to be waiting for it.

Here's `parent.js`

```
import { fork } from "child_process";

console.log(`process.pid: ${process.pid}`);

process.on("beforeExit", () => {
  console.log("parent exiting...");
});

const forked = fork("./child.js", {
  detached: true,
  stdio: "ignore",
});

forked.unref();
```

and here's `child.js`

```
const main = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("resolving");
      resolve();
    }, 10 * 1000);
  });
};

main();
```

The `child.js` is a trivial script, but my use-case involves the child process to run some computation for a specified duration, which would be 10,20 secs.

When running the code above, the `beforeExit` event is emitted only after 10 secs, which is when the child process should be exiting. But according to the code and docs, shouldn't the parent be exiting as soon as the child process is created? Or rather, `unref()`-ed?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear to me exactly what the docs say should be happening (your interpretation seems reasonable to me), but what IS happening -- at least on Node v14.19.2 -- is that you have an event loop reference for the IPC pipe between the two processes. If you set the timeout option, you will also have an event loop reference on that timer. Whether or not you called unref().

In order to get this working, what I found I needed to do was disconnect the IPC handle. This may, or may not, be a problem for you.  Of course, disconnecting the IPC handle yields another problem: the process doesn't die, and instead gets owned by pid 1...unless you explicitly kill it during exit.

So, the general solution -- assuming you don't need the IPC pipe after initial launch -- is, after you're finished with the IPC socket,

```js
    child.disconnect();
    process.on('exit', () => child.kill());
```